# How to add a SQL function to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working with Oracle SQL and I want to use some of Oracle's function that don't exist in other types of relational databases.

Basically I want to add function that return a weekday for a given date.

From what I understand sqlachemy gives me two way to do that, one is provide sql query as text, another exend sqlalchemy implementing a new python function that represents the SQL function. I'm leaning torwards implementing the function because I expect to use this in few queries.

Here is what I implemented so far to get this done, I'm not really sure what is my next step, or if this is even correct.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
class weekday(FunctionElement):
  name= 'weekday'


@compiles(weekday)
def complie(element, compiler, **kw):
  if len(element.clauses) == 1:
    return "TO_CHAR(%s,'DY')" % compiler.process(element.clauses)
  elif len(element.clauses) == 0:
    raise TypeError("Weekday needs a date as parameter")
  else:
    raise TypeError("Weekday needs just one parameter")
```

When I tried to add this funtion for one of my objects instead of caculating results I got the function istelf back, here is an example of what I'm taking about:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class SomeObject(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'table1'
  asof = Column(Date,primary_key=True)
  
  @hybrid_property
  def weekday(self):
      return weekday(self.asof)
```

In shell I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_object = SomeObject()
my_object.asof = datetime(2018,1,1) 
session.add(my_object)
session.commit()

result = session.query(SomeObject).filter(SomeObject.asof == datetime(2018,1,1)).first()
result.weekday # returns `<orm.weekday as 0x1724b7deeb8; weekday>`
```

#### NOTE

I insist on extracting that weekday in SQL query rather than in python because I need this to filter out some records, and in my case that funtion will determine if sqlalchemy pulls out couple million or just couple records.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out few things I realized that hybrid_property is not supposed to return a sql expression, it needs to return the actual value that sql expression would have returned.
Thta being said my sql function would go into the 'expression' part of hybrid_property which would look like this:

```
@weekday.expression
def weekday(cls):
  return weekday(cls.asof)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can also use sqlachemy's SQL and Generic Functions:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html

Comment: To be honest I haven't spent much time of Core APi, but you bring up a good point apparently it is more flexible than ORM